# Android:socket communication

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to create simple app with android client and java server
android client is able to send message to server(java)
while when i try to read server reply
error:socket closed.
line(if((receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()) != null) )

```
public class ClientConnectorTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    protected Integer doInBackground(String...strings) {
        // validate input parameters
        if (strings.length <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        // connect to the server and send the message
        try {
            client = new Socket("192.168.1.4", 7777);
            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);

            //while(true){
            InputStream istream = client.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader receiveRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));

            String  receiveMessage;
            while (true){
            //  printwriter.write(strings[0]);
                printwriter.print(strings[0]);
                printwriter.flush();
                printwriter.close();
                if((receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()) != null) //receive from server
                {
                    System.out.println(receiveMessage); // displaying at DOS prompt
                } 
            }
            //}

            //client.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this, that's why it's a comment. I believe this ``printwriter.close();`` might be closing the socket. However, as I said I'm not sure. If you remove it will it still throw the error? Also, are you sure you're not closing it on the server side?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.in server side i am not closing. if i dont do it then data doesn't reach server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the `PrintWriter` inside the loop doesn't make sense, and closing it before the `readLine()` call doesn't make sense either. Closing either the input or the output stream of a `Socket` closes the other stream and the socket.